# Every countable linearly ordered set is similar to one of its subsets

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, model-theory

Below is the exact quote from textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech.

> **4.1 Definition** Linearly ordered sets $(A,<)$ and $(B,\prec)$ are *similar* (*have the same order type*) if they are isomorphic, i.e., if there is a one-to-one mapping $f$ on $A$ onto $B$ such that for all $a_1,a_2\in A,a_1<a_2$ holds if and only if $f(a_1) \prec f(a_2)$ holds.
>
> The previous results show that there is a rich variety of types of linear orderings on countable sets. It is thus rather surprising to learn that there
> is a universal linear ordering of countable sets, i.e., such that every countable linearly ordered set is similar to one of its subsets. The rest of this section is devoted to the proof of this important result.

In this textbook, $A$ is countable $\iff$ $A$ is countably infinite.

While I can prove below statement for $\Bbb N$, I'm unable to prove it

> i.e., such that every countable linearly ordered set is similar to one of its subsets.

for countable linearly ordered set in general. Please shed me some lights!

Comment: What is your proposed universal countable linear order into which you are trying to embed?

Comment: Hi @Apollo, I even don't understand which *a universal linear ordering* that the authors are mentioning. I'm just concerned about the statement *every countable linearly ordered set is similar to one of its subsets* from that quote.

Comment: I don't quite understand if you want a set $B$ such that every countable total order is isomorphic to a subset of $B$ (as the authors suggest) or if you want to prove that for all countably infinite totally ordered set $B$ there is some $A\subsetneq B$ such that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic (as the pronoun game you have played in the title says).

Comment: Hi @SaucyO'Path! I think I misunderstand the authors' intention. Actually, I quite don't understand the statement *It is thus rather surprising to learn that there is a universal linear ordering of countable sets, i.e., such that every countable linearly ordered set is similar to one of its subsets*. Please elaborate!

Comment: That statement means that there is some countable total order $B$ such as in first thing I said.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path, Is it that $\Bbb Q$ is one of the $B$s?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much @SaucyO'Path! I'm now clear :)